# Bringing a table in front of a transparent foto

Tags: html, layout, html-table, header

I am a complete beginner so I'm sorry if this sounds like a stupid question. I am trying to make the header for a forum that uses tables for layout. The header itself is a photo (not a div or a header tag) that's transparent.

I need to create a three columns table where the first and the last column contain pictures and text and the middle column contains the title of the forum. My problem is when I try to put some fotos to the right and left of the forum title, they fall behind the picture and become blured due to the transparency.

So, my question is how do I get the table from behind the ''header'' picture in front of it so that the pictures to the right and left don't get bluder

Comment: What did you try up to now? Please show your code as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's ok ) I just needed to use a z-index. Thank you for answering though )